# Developing for iphone 5 resolution, what happens with 4s resolution?

Tags: iphone, retina-display, iphone-5

I have a doubt about iphone 5 resolution, seems that xcode 4.5 has added a new view size type name "retina 4 full screen" (it's on attributes inspector).

[image]

If I try to use this resolution to a view and run it on the iphone 5.1 simulator, it crashes.

so, is there a way to develop to iphone 5 having support to iphone 4 or before?

the console message says:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use it on 5.1 simulator. Only iOS 6 is supported on the iPhone 5.

Comment: Tested it on an iPhone 4S or a 3GS? With what iOS version?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use AutoLayout and run the app in anything running less than iOS 6. You can indeed develop for iPhone 5 having and still support iPhone 4 or before provided your deployment target is set to iOS 6.0. If you still want to support older iOS versions, uncheck "Use Autolayout" for the NIB file.